# Embed YouTube Playlist plugin with sidebar list visible

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I know that the YouTube API does not provide functionality to display a playlist sidebar similar to the native YouTube playlist at this time.

Through searching I found a promising plugin to imitate this behavior. https://github.com/jakiestfu/Youtube-TV

Unfortunately, this plugin no longer works with YouTube's API v.3, however, Giorgio003 created a fork with API v.3 support.
https://github.com/Giorgio003/Youtube-TV

I have followed all the installation instructions, but cannot seem to get it to work.

This is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="src/ytv.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="src/ytv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  Testing YouTube Playlist
</div>

<div id="YourPlayerID"></div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var controller = new YTV('YourPlayerID', {
       channelId: 'UCBSvZIJlXJR7SE_KNvOiiGg'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In ytv.js I included my API key

```
(function(win, doc) {
    'use strict';
    var apiKey = 'ThisIsARealKeyForMyChannel';
    var YTV = YTV || function(id, opts){...
```

The ytv.js script seems to be running fine. It correctly finds my channel and the two sample videos I have uploaded. The rendered HTML for `#YourPlayerID` looks like this:

```
<div id="YourPlayerID" class="ytv-canvas">
    <div class="ytv-relative">
        <div class="ytv-video">
            <iframe id="ytv-video-playerYourPlayerID0" class="ytv-video-playerContainer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VqWWn-NrebU?enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fdevcf9.acm.org&amp;controls=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;autoplay=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;wmode=opaque&amp;widgetid=1"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="ytv-list">
            <div class="ytv-list-header">
                <a href="//youtube.com/channel/UCBSvZIJlXJR7SE_KNvOiiGg" target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/-IGpxPi95eQQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/z-D0JYX_Wog/s88-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg">
                    <span><i class="ytv-arrow down"></i>My Name</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="ytv-list-inner">
                <ul>
                    <li class="ytv-active">
                        <a href="#" data-ytv="VqWWn-NrebU" class="ytv-clear">
                            <div class="ytv-thumb">
                                <div class="ytv-thumb-stroke"></div>
                                <span>00:42</span>
                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/VqWWn-NrebU/mqdefault.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="ytv-content">
                                <b>Skin   4144</b>
                                <span class="ytv-views">1 Views</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" data-ytv="bAWFo5ur9fc" class="ytv-clear">
                            <div class="ytv-thumb">
                                <div class="ytv-thumb-stroke"></div>
                                <span>00:16</span>
                                <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bAWFo5ur9fc/mqdefault.jpg">
                            </div>
                            <div class="ytv-content"><b>Nebula   6044</b>
                                <span class="ytv-views">0 Views</span>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But no video or playlist appears on the page. Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: I should also note that I am running this on a development server. I have sometimes noticed that youtube embeds do not work properly when running a page locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. All the elements created from the plugin set the height to 100%. The element `<div id="YourPlayerID"></div>` had a height of `0`, therefore, all its children had a height of `0`. Once I gave the `#YourPlayerID` element a height the playlist appeared.