# How can I pre-populate youtube playlist videos in the right side embedded in html without using playlist button

Tags: html, jquery, youtube

I am working on a project where I need to embed youtube playlist in a div.
I am doing it with following code. but I am not getting expected result.

The code which I have found is ..

```
<iframe width="100%" style="height: calc(35vw);" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PLq6t3Vjkzc9p1BhTiXon6EAdSwg5Iqxlb" rel="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>                                        
</iframe>
```

and this generates this UI

[image]

Whereas I want playlist videos already to be shown there at the right side like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It actually has a sidebar, but it can be oppened by pressing the button left to "Watch later"

Also check this post
[How to embed a youtube playlist with a sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459015/how-to-embed-a-youtube-playlist-with-a-sidebar)

Comment: I know i should set a duplicate flag, but i don't have the reputation requirements to do it

Comment: I don't want to click that button. It should be pre-populated